# library not found. Trying to compile a program including Lapack (C++)

Tags: c++, compilation, lapack

I might be violating all posting rules about duplication, but really I'm desperate looking for information two days in a row and I found nothing useful for this simple but aweful problem.

I just want to compilate a code c.cpp with the command

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -llapack -lblas program.cpp -o program.o
```

I sincerely don't know if I have to write in the code #include lapack, #include "lapack", #include lapack.a, #include liblapack.a...
The situation is that I have a liblapack.a linked file located at usr/lib.

Where is the problem? I have tried all possible combinations...

It's the first time I use libraries who are not the classical stdio.h, cmath, etc.

Thank you very much :)

Just edited: I realized that the words between "<" and the corresponding closing "more than" disappear.

Answer (score 1):

In program.cpp you do need to #include the relevant header files.  Only way to know what those are is to know what the code uses.  I imagine when you try to compile you get some error messages telling you what names are undefined.

Comment: How to know what follows the #include? for example, in my case I have a liblapack.a in usr/lib. Can we deduce from that what should be included? Or where should I look at to know it? Thank you very much! And yes, when #include XX, the error is always "Could not find XX. Compilation terminated".

Comment: To know what to include, you need to read the docs for the library.  No other way other than grepping and guessing from the files installed on your system.  Better read the docs.

Comment: The docs don't say anything, just things about how to use each function. I found in an example provided by Lapack that it should be lapacke.h (with an e), however when trying to compile the example it doesn't work (error: Cannot find lapacke.h, what a surprise). This is so cryptical... If you have some ideas, I would thank you, but if you don't, thank you anyway, I'll continue searching on the web and trying out string combinations...

Comment: Do you have lapacke.h installed on your system?  Or lapack anything else?  Do a search of your filesystem.  What OS are you using?  If Linux, perhaps you have installed the runtime package containing the library but not the "dev" or "devel" package containing the headers needed to build against the library.

Comment: Maybe that's the reason, because I do not have any .h file, just a liblapack.a file, result of doing "make" when downloading the library. I think will delete all and start again, the classical way. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Sorry, I am on Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Then you should `sudo apt-get install lapack-dev` instead of building from source.

Comment: I have tried deleting all files related to lapack/blas/etc., and then try sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev. But it says: Lapack newest version is already installed. This is amazing...

Comment: Try `dpkg -L liblapack-dev` and see what headers it has installed.  It will tell you the full list of files installed from that package, which may give you some hint.